# AngularJs router disturbing javascript action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ngroute

I try to implement the portfolio-filter from this website "http://shapebootstrap.net/demo/html/flat_theme/portfolio.html" into my AngularJs App

And when I use it inside my Angular application, when I click on one filter, it understand a link and goes in my otherwise route to return a view.

How can I tell it to not use my router when I have a href with # ?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to put `target=_self` on the `<a>` tag which has such url.

If you read the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) guide, the section "Html link rewriting" mentions this fact.

Comment: That doesnt call the anonyme fonction. It does enable the external click